# returntype Promise<this>

Tags: typescript, types, this

I know typescript [supports return type `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types). Which may be what I need, except that I have a static method which returns an instance of the class that defines it *or a subclass of it*. So Im trying to use:

```
class A {
    static createInstance(resource):Promise<this> //<---what can I put here??
    {
        //pseudo code: load a module, async
        return loadModule(resource.module).then(() => {
            //find Class from resource data, can return A, or B or any subclass
            var targetClass = resource.getType().getClass();
            //create instance of A or any subclass of A
            return new targetClass.prototype.constructor();
        }
    }
}
//module B.js which is loaded on demand:
class B extends A {
    //I dont want to have to overwrite the returntype of createInstance
    //in every subclass of A
}
```

`Promise<this>` does not work. Nor does `Promise<typeof this>`. Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: Would you mind providing some context from the surrounding code? Usually such methods are static.

Comment: yes you are right, the method I'm actually using is static. I updated the code with what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When returning `this` you must return the current instance.
As the instance already exists, you shouldn't need to return a `Promise` to it.

If you want to return a `Promise` to a subclass of `this` then it means that you don't really want to return `this`, but an instance of a subclass of the class of `this`, which isn't what this feature is about.

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
    x: number = 0;

    add(y: number): this {
        this.x += y;
        return this;
    }

    sub(y: number): this {
        this.x -= y;
        return new B() as this;
    }
}

class B extends A { }

let a1 = new A();
console.log(a1.add(3).add(5).x); // 8

let a2 = new A();
console.log(a2.add(3).sub(2).x); // 0
```

The 2nd `console.log` should be printing `1` and not `0` based on the "construct", as returning `this` should **always** return the **current instance**.

---

#### Edit

There's currently no way of doing that.
There's an open issue for that: [Polymorphic "this" for static members](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) and their example is pretty much what you want to do.

---

#### 2nd Edit

It is a must to return the current instance and not just an instance of "this class", a simple example:

```
class A {
    fn1(): this {
        return this;
    }

    fn2(): this {
        return new A(); // Error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'this'
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn1()%3A%20this%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn2()%3A%20this%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20A()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Type%20'A'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'this'%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Comment: Ok, I understand that `this` can probably not be used. Tnx for the clarifying example. I've made my example code more complete to explain what I'm trying to do, do you know how I _can_ define the return type for this example?

Comment: In your updated example, the resource argument should determine the type. You can achieve this by overloading the function declaration based on the type of the `resource` argument. For example, you could use a string literal type.

Comment: Actually it looks like `resource` provides the actual type, so a type argument, constrained as extending `A`, would probably be more appropriate. That said the entire approach looks awkward. Why not just call a method on `resource` directly?

Comment: "When returning this you must return the current instance." this is not correct. The type `this` simply means that it is of the same type as the target instance.

Comment: Check out my revised answer. @AluanHaddad That is indeed correct, if your return type is `this` then you must return the exact instance, checkout the builder pattern to understand why.

Comment: I think your answer is correct thanks for linking that GitHub issue as it is indeed relevant. In general you do probably want to `return this` for a `this` type but I don't think it is mandatory so long as the value returned matches the `this` type. In other words I wouldn't assume that reference equality would hold

Comment: @AluanHaddad It is mandatory. Check my 2nd edit of the answer

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer, the issue you mentioned about polymorphic this in static methods contains [the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-242782664) that solves exactly my usecase

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
static createInstance<T>(resource): Promise<T>
```

Comment: Ah yeah that's a possibility, but then Ill be typing `B.createInstance<B>(resource).then(b => ...)` which is not much different from what I have now: `B.cteateInstance(resourse).then((b:B) => ...)` .. Im asking this question to see if I can get rid of typing `B` twice in this very often used command